# ¿Cómo usar JS en html?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estoy haciendo un proyecto web en *netbeans* con *jsp* y nos pidieron darle diseño por lo que estoy usando *bootstrap*, entiendo como usar el *css* pero el *js* no sé cómo usarlo.

Tengo un código de *js* que quiero usar pero no sé cómo meterlo, sólo sé que tengo que llamarlo del *html* con el `id`

**Código**

```
$(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Sé que se tiene que meter en una de las carpetas que trae *bootstrap* por defecto, pero no sé.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes meterlo dentro de un archivo distinto de bootstrap por ejemplo en un **functions.js** o bien en el mismo archivo que de tu html como lo muestro aquí abajo has la prueba.

En este nuevo archivo puedes poner esa función por ejemplo:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Aqui el codigo que agregarias !-->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#btnSesion").click(function(e) {
        $("#formularioRegistro").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#formulario").fadeOut(100);
        $('#formulario').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      $("#btnRegistrar").click(function(e) {
        $("#formulario").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#formularioRegistro").fadeOut(100);
        $('#formularioRegistro').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form id="formulario">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Sesion" />

  </form>
  <br/>
  <form id="formularioRegistro">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Registro" />
  </form>
  <button id="btnSesion">Sesion</button>
  <button id="btnRegistrar">Registrar</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes meterlo en el mismo archivo *html* donde están los elementos con los `id` que utiliza el *script* (i.e. aquellos que tienen `#`), ya sea en dentro del `header` o al final del archivo. Sólo debes meterlo dentro del tag `script`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
          $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
          $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
          $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
          $(this).addClass('active');
          e.preventDefault();
     });
     $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
          $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
          $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
          $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
         $(this).addClass('active');
         e.preventDefault();
    });

});
</script>
```